# How to run varirables on client only

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I am trying to modify a mod in Minecraft called Psychedelicraft on 1.7.10 and i have some problems with client/server side.

How can I keep these variables private. How can I keep it running only on client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep in mind that outside of the client and server annotations (`@ClientOnly` and `@ServerOnly` if I remember correctly), everything runs on both the client and the server. However, you need to manage keeping the two up to date with each other.

So if you only want the client to know some data, just don't send it to the server. In other words don't add it to any nbt data or serialization. The downside to this is that when the game is restarted, the server won't be able to get the client back up to date.

Comment: Ok so i need to make a class and mark it @ClientOnly and update these variables there ??

here's the code [CODE](https://pastebin.pl/view/76d9a98a)

the variables that am trying to run only on client is the 

    `private static int addiction
     private static int tobbacoSmoked
     private static boolean isAddicted`

Comment: No, those annotations are only for conditional compilation and it sounds like you do want to share that information with the server, but  not with other players. The best way to do that is to just... not send that data to other players. Remember you have to send data explicitly since theres nothing there that will magically sync it for you.